# Python code parallelization using multiprocessing

Tags: python, bash, parallel-processing, multiprocessing, hdf

I am really new to python mutli-processing and trying to parallelize my code because its taking too long to run. I have a code that runs through a large chunk of data to find if any of the files are corrupted or not. So far my code is:

```
def check_Corrupt_1(dirPath, logfile):

    fileCheck = open(logfile, "w").close()
    fileCheck = open(logfile, "w")

    emptydir = []
    zero_size = {}
    #entering the year to be checked (day number)
    for fname in os.listdir(dirPath):

        if(os.listdir(os.path.join(dirPath, fname)) == []):
            emptydir.append(fname)

        else:

            #this makes sure that we do not enter an empty directory
            if fname not in emptydir:
                inPath = os.path.join(dirPath, fname)

                for filename in os.listdir(inPath):
                    hdfinfo = os.stat(os.path.join(inPath, filename))

                    if(hdfinfo.st_size == 0):
                        zero_size[filename] = True

                    else:

                        filepath = "/path/to/file"

                        strin = subprocess.Popen(["hdp", "dumpsds", "-h", os.path.join(inPath, filename)], stdout=subprocess.PIPE).communicate()[0]
                        #print(strin)
                        cmd = 'echo $?'
                        callno = subprocess.Popen(cmd, shell=True, stdout=subprocess.PIPE)
                        #print(int(callno.stdout.read()[0]))
                        if(int(callno.stdout.read()[0]) != 0):
                            fileCheck.write(os.path.join(inPath, filename) + '\n')
```

I have 365 directories for each year and each directory contains a lot of files to check. I am running bash commands to check if the file is corrupt or not but because the bash command I am running has a very long output this code is taking a lot of time to run. I am hoping that parallelization will help make it faster but don't understand how to do that. Is there another way to make it faster other than multiprocessing? I would appreciate any help.

Answer (score 1):

From a brief skim through of your write-up and the code segment you posted, it seems the majority of the heavy lifting seems to be done via the `hdp` command. So that's the one you want to `parallelize`.
What you seem to be doing is opening up a subprocess. 
You could also try to use threads. Your code would be something like this

```
#!/usr/bin/python
import thread
from subprocess import call

def check_Corrupt_1(dirPath, logfile):

    fileCheck = open(logfile, "w").close()
    fileCheck = open(logfile, "w")

    emptydir = []
    zero_size = {}
    #entering the year to be checked (day number)
    for fname in os.listdir(dirPath):

        if(os.listdir(os.path.join(dirPath, fname)) == []):
            emptydir.append(fname)

        else:

            #this makes sure that we do not enter an empty directory
            if fname not in emptydir:
                inPath = os.path.join(dirPath, fname)

                for filename in os.listdir(inPath):
                    hdfinfo = os.stat(os.path.join(inPath, filename))

                    if(hdfinfo.st_size == 0):
                        zero_size[filename] = True

                    else:
                        try:    
                            thread.start_new_thread(call(["hdp", "dumpsds", "-h"]))
                        except:
                            print "Error generating thread"

                        if(int(callno.stdout.read()[0]) != 0):
                            fileCheck.write(os.path.join(inPath, filename) + '\n')
```

Comment: For some reason, this is printing the error for every file. The only thing I changed from your code is that I gave a filepath in the call function.